# How to load dynamic data on a eclipse shell?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to load details of a user's when clicking their names . So I create a Grid Layout with two columns left hand side is standalone and right hand side data will be loaded based on clicking their names .

**JAVA CODE**

```
Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setSize(400, 400);
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
gridLayout.numColumns = 2;
shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

shell.setBackground(new Color(display, 255, 255, 255));
final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.VIRTUAL);
table.setLayout(new GridLayout());
table.setSize(400, 400);
final TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
column.setWidth(150);
column.setText("Runnable Services");
table.setItemCount(5);
final String[] services = new String[] { "Franklin", "Christian",
    "Richard Levi",
    "Dale Steyn", "Chris Gayle" };
table.addListener(SWT.SetData, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
    int index = table.indexOf(item);
    item.setText(services[index]);
    System.out.println(item.getText());
    }
});

table.addSelectionListener(new OnClickListener());
alignCenter(shell, display);
shell.open();
```

I added a selection listener on a table . When click the players I add their details on SelectionListener's widget Selected method .

**JAVA CODE**

```
Composite parent = new Composite(table.getParent(), SWT.NONE);
parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.NULL);
label.setText("Name :");
System.out.println(table.getSelection()[0].getText());
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
text.setText(table.getSelection()[0].getText());
text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL
            | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
ViewActionDelegate.resize(200, true, 20, table.getShell());
```

If i did like this on click action each time data will be appended to existing shell . How can I clear the righ hand side details ? . I posted a image below .
[image]

How can i do this ? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer .

Issue :
 I append new elements into already created composite .

Solution:
 Clear elements from existing composite before drawing new elements .

Java Code :

```
if ((composite != null) && (!composite.isDisposed())) {
             Control[] children = composite2.getChildren();
             for(Control ch : children){
                 ch.dispose();
             }
            }
```